# How to fetch Azure Active Directory User Details using Azure CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the count of users, user names for a given active directory group. For ex, If AAD Group A had 2 members, B & C, I need to get both the user details.

Just a few days back, I was logging to Azure using my organization email id and password would be access token and it would work perfectly fine:

`az account get-access-token --resource "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com"`

`az login --username {user_name} --tenant {tenant_id} --password {access_token}`

`az ad group member list --group {AAD_group_name}`

Since access token expires every 1 hour, I would get the new token programatically and get the AAD user details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPvoE.jpg)

But when I run the 2nd step now, I get an error:
***RuntimeError: WsTrust server returned error in RSTR: {'reason': 'ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.', 'code': 'a:FailedAuthentication'}***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8etW7.jpg)

Is there any other alternative where *AZ CLI* can talk to AAD and get the details?
Because I tried with SPN as well but it says:

***Insufficient privileges to complete the operation*.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGJg7.jpg)

I want to get AAD group details using Azure CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of Azure CLI you are using there is a [feature gap](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22664) where service principals are not listed as group members. As a workaround you can use az rest to call the beta API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

See related issues:
[Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/999734/az-ad-group-member-list-not-returning-results)
[Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22664)

In Powershell you can use Get-AzureADGroupMember

To list all group members:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId df095002-f3ae-9077-6720-3a095edd8ff4 | Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $True
```

To list the top 50 members:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId df095002-f3ae-9077-6720-3a095edd8ff4 | Get-AzureADGroupMember -Top 50
```

**Edit**: Make sure to connect to the tenant before running the commands using `Connect-Azuread -TenantID <your tenantid>`

Comment: I tried but I get 
Get-AzureADgroup: Error occurred while executing GetGroup
Code: Authentication_MissingOrMalformed
Message: Access token missing or malformed
HttpStatusCode: Unathorized
HttpStatusDescription: Unauthorized

Comment: Have you specified the tenant when connecting? Connect-Azuread -TenantID <your tenantid>

Comment: It worked after trying above command

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I updated the post to include that step.

Comment: If this is resolved it would help to accept the answer. Otherwise let me know if anything is missing!